# db.update does db.insert instead

Tags: android, sqlite

Anyone got an idea why this code does an insert instead of an update?  It doesnt fail, it just does an insert. Thus jacking up the db.

```
 String[] cur_row = {String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition())};
 values.put("colA", dataA);
 values.put("colB", dataB);
 values.put("colC", dataC);

 db.beginTransaction();
 try{
    db.update("tbl2", values, "_id=?", cur_row);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("FAIL: " + e);
 }
 finally{
     db.endTransaction();
 }
```

Many thanks

Comment: I'm just guessing here, since I've seen this behavior when working with JEE2. When performing an `update` call, it might be that if the row doesn't exists, `update`. inserts the row. What `update` does behind the scene is, removing the existing items and then inserting again with provided values. Again, I don't have anything to back this up, so.. But that would be my guess.

Comment: An `update` *cannot* create new rows. Why do you think it does?

Comment: LOL @CL! I know update isn't suppose to create a new row.  But the above code does create a new row and thus I asked the question here.   Every time I process the update, I get a new row in my db.  And yes the row was already there to be updated.   @Marcus You are correct about the way update functions.  The row I am trying to update does exist already.  That is why I am baffled by the way the code is basically doing an insert and not an update.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cur_row was getting out of sync from the time it was assigned at the SCA to the time the update occurred. values.put("colA", dataA) was provided from an auto complete text view. I didn't think that mattered when I posted this question. For the whereArgs, for the update, I used the .getItemId(position) of the SCA selected item and then assigning it to a variable to pass to the whereArgs.  Thank you to those that posted.